# Create JSON string from three or more tables in T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server

I have three tables, one master and two details tables.

Master table1

```
Student
Rollno
```

Table2 Terminal-1

```
Subject1
Subject2
Subject3
Rollno
```

Table3  Terminal-2

```
Subject1
Subject2
Subject3
Rollno
```

I need to get a JSON string from these tables in the below format

```
[
    {
        "Student": "RAMKUMAR",
        "RollNo": "12345",
        "Terminal-1": [
            {
                "subject1": "",
                "subject2": "",
                "subject3": ""
            }
        ],
        "Terminal-2": [
            {
                "subject1": "",
                "subject2": "",
                "subject3": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Kindly help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `FOR JSON` clause to your select statement to get result in JSON format. You can refer [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for more detail.

Comment: Official document deals only with two tables or single table. There is no use of it, I tried Crossapply, joins, JSON PATH, JSON AUTO. So